# TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView not working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

hi i found TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView in github and i followed the explanation but it didn't work

```
#import "ajouterBilanViewController.h" 
#import "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h"

@interface ajouterBilanViewController ()

@end

@implementation ajouterBilanViewController
@synthesize scroll;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{  
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

i added a scroll view in my xib and changed uiscrollview with TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView
but nothing is working.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView;
@interface ajouterBilanViewController : UIViewController
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *scroll;
 @end
```

Comment: @user31227590 you should check my answer

Comment: Did you checked my answer,let me know if it will be useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is How can you make it work,

Hope this will help you..
[image: You need to set your custom class as shown]

**REST WILL BE MANAGED BY TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView  FOR YOU**